# Make List from text file and compare to second list. Remove lines that contain matching text Python

Tags: python

I am very new to python and trying to learn.

I am attempting to Make List from one text file and compare to a second list. From the second list I want to Remove lines that contains matching text from from first list. I have put something together that works but is far from efficient. It is very CPU intensive and if I am comparing lists with 400k lines it takes an extensive amount of time. I'm happy that I was able to get it to work but know that it's far from perfect.

```
exe. of what should happen<br />
textFile1.txt contains list<br />
aJkk_990sva<br />
rVsw_837rma<br />
trTv_275wwm<br />
<br />
textFile2.txt contains list<br />
rVsw_837rma;withMoreText;orNumbers<br />
hYuz_237top;withMoreText;orNumbers<br />
trTv_275wwm;withMoreText;orNumbers<br />
kLnm_727mvp;withMoreText;orNumbers<br />

NewTextFile3.txt now contains<br />
hYuz_237top;withMoreText;orNumbers<br />
kLnm_727mvp;withMoreText;orNumbers<br />
<br />
```

This is what I was able to put together:

```
lineList = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('C:/Documents/myFirstList.txt')]

bad_words = (lineList)

with open('C:/Documents/mySecondList.txt') as oldfile, open('C:/Documents/mySecondListWithOutBadWords.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if not any(bad_word in line for bad_word in bad_words):
            newfile.write(line)
```

Comment: Please format your inputs properly

Comment: first, use a `set` for `bad_words`, because checking if something is `in` a set is much faster (constant time complexity) than in a list: `bad_words = set(bad_words)`. Then extract the word and check if it's in bad words: `word = line.split(";")[0]` then `if word not in bad_words: newfile.write(line)`